# Is it possible to read the state of a specific printer part from the firmware, such as the power of a stepper motor, LCD brightness, or fan speed RPM?

Tags: marlin, firmware, electronics, mriscoc

Is it possible to read the state of a specific printer part from Marlin-based firmware such as [mriscoc](https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1), such as:

- the power (on or off) of a particular stepper motor;
- the brightness percentage of the LCD screen;
- fan speed of individual fans (in RPM);
- stepper motor voltage et cetera?

Preferably through the use of certain G-codes.